# Charge density is the amount of charge per unit volume but what is charge?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, electrons, crystal-structure, ionic-compounds

I was studying about x ray crystallography and my book says that charge density is measured in electrons per nano-meter cubed and this means that charge is the amount of electrons. But i am not sure if this definition (charge density = the number of electrons in a unit volume) applies when we are studying crystallography only. So to make sure, is charge simply the amount of electrons ?

Comment: The electron has a charge measure in coulombs of $\approx 1.602\cdot 10^{-19}$ C. In a given volume  v ($\pu{m^{3}}$) the charge density for *n* electrons is $ne/\mathrm{v}$ with unit $\pu{C m^{-3}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An electron has a charge (lets say $e [C]$). If you have a certain amount of electrons in a certain volume ($V [m^3]$), you have a certain charge per volume $\rho = e/V [\frac{C}{m^3}]$. Which is a density.

Comment: The charge of the electron is measure in Coulombs not volts.

Comment: @porphyrin The units don't matter to make my point, but I'll change it